# How to get the string name which has failed consecutively for 3 days in powershell

Tags: powershell, shell, date

I have data in a text file with the following columns.

| Date | StringName |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1/2021 | ABC |
| 2/1/2021 | ABC |
| 3/1/2021 | ABC |
| 1/1/2021 | XYZ |
| 2/1/2021 | XYZ |
| 3/1/2021 | ABC |
| 4/1/2021 | ZZZ |

I want only the StringName in the output which has consecutively failed for 3 days or more & ignore the rest. In the above data, ABC has failed for 1 2 3 days consecutively in Calendar month January. So the output should be ABC. If there are more than one stringName then the output should be like below

| StringName |
| --- |
| ABC |
| XYZ |

Comment: Have you actually tried anything yourself? Please post the code you have so far.

Comment: I haven't tried anything as i am stuck on how to start with the logic.

Comment: Ok then, to start you can have a look `Get-ChildItem` and any type of loop (`foreach` would fit best in my opinion but it's up to your preferences).

Comment: What is the input file that contains the data? A csv file, xlsx, just text? Pleas show us the real sanitized file instead of an image

Comment: Ah, not an image.. this is how SO renders a table.. The question remains however. Can we see the real format of the file please.

Comment: [1] use `Import-Csv` to load the data from what seems to be a CSV file. if it is just text, use `Get-Content`. [2] use `Group-Object` to group by the `.StringName` property. [3] sort that by date & check for "3-in-a-row". [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I was able to achieve this. Thank you all

```
$file_data = get-content "c:\temp\txt.txt"

$dict_counter = @{}

$dict_dates = @{}

Foreach ($line in $file_data)

{

$values = $line.split(" ")

$pattern = '\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}'

[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]$regex = New-Object System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex($pattern)

[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match]$m = $regex.Match($line)

if($m.Success)

{

$current_date = $m.Value

$sch_name = $values[7]

if($dict_dates.containsKey($sch_name))

{

  $existing_date = $dict_dates.get_item($sch_name)

  if($existing_date -ne $current_date)

  {

    $existing_date_format = [datetime]::parseexact($existing_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd', $null)

    $current_date_format = [datetime]::parseexact($current_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd', $null)

    $difference = (new-timespan -start $existing_date_format -end $current_date_format).days

    if($dict_counter.containsKey($sch_name))

    {

      $diff = $dict_counter.get_item($sch_name)

      $diff_new = [string]$diff + "," + [string]$difference

      $dict_counter.set_item($sch_name, $diff_new)

    }

    else

    {

      $dict_counter.add($sch_name, $difference)

    }

    }

    }

  else

 {

  $dict_dates.add($sch_name, $current_date)

  $dict_counter.add($sch_name, 0)

  }

 }

 }

$fail_count = 0

$flagSequence = $false

$seqcounter = 0

Foreach ($value in $dict_counter.values)

 {

if($value -ne 0)

{

$arr1 = $value.split(",")

$arr = foreach($number in $arr1){([int]::parse($number))}

$arr = $arr | sort

For($i = 1; $i -lt $arr.count; $i++)

{

  $prev = $arr[$i - 1]

  $curr = $arr[$i]

  $dff = $curr - $prev

  if(($dff -eq 1) -or ($dff -eq -1))

  {

    $flagSequence = $true

    $seqcounter += 1

  }

  else

  {

    $flagSequence = $false

    $seqcounter = 0

  }

}

if($seqcounter -ge 2)

{

  $fail_count += 1

}

}

}

$dict_counter

$fail_count
```